# Outlook.MailItem fails sometimes

Tags: .net, outlook

While iterating through email items, sometimes system cannot get mail item but it will get the same email item in the next run. Below is the sample of the code I am using to get mail items.

```
        var oApplicationClass = new Application();
        NameSpace nameSpace = oApplicationClass.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox = nameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
        Outlook.MAPIFolder deletedItems = nameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDeletedItems);

        MailItem mailItem;


        var safeMail = new Redemption.SafeMailItem();
        Items outlookItems = inbox.Items.Restrict("[MessageClass] = \"IPM.Note\"");
        int totalCount = outlookItems.Count;
        string subject = "";
        bool filterMessage = filters.Count > 0;

        if (totalCount > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= totalCount; i++)
            {
                outlookItems.Sort("[ReceivedTime]",
                                  sortAscending ? OlSortOrder.olAscending : OlSortOrder.olDescending);

                try
                {
                    mailItem = (MailItem) outlookItems[i];
                    var testCount = mailItem.Attachments.Count;
                    //Code to move the email to deleted items
                }
                catch (Exception oEx)
                {
                    Logger.Debug("Mail item cannot be acquired, continuing to other mail items.");
                    Logger.Debug(oEx.Message);
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why do you call `outlookItems.Sort` in every iteration?

Comment: You are right, might be a poor coding practice. Actually, it is an existing code, I was just looking into this particular issue of missing some emails. Thanks for pointing out, I should take it out of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to release *all* underlying COM objects instantly. Use *System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject* to release an Outlook object when you have finished using it. Then set a variable to Nothing in Visual Basic (null in C#) to release the reference to the object.

This is particularly important if your add-in attempts to enumerate more than 256 Outlook items in a collection that is stored on a Microsoft Exchange Server. If you do not release these objects in a timely manner, you can reach the limit imposed by Exchange on the maximum number of items opened at any one time.

For example, you can find a sample code in the [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/) article.

Comment: Hi Eugene, Thanks for your quick and valuable response. I have tried the solution given by you, it does not work all the times, unfortunately, though I have less than 50 mail items. Sometimes, system still misses some of the mail items. I have then put system on sleep for few milliseconds after every iteration and it can get all the emails. I agree that it is something to do with releasing the COM object but how can we make sure that COM object is released. I can release outlook object only after finishing one cycle of iteration but the system fails even on first iteration.

Comment: Moreover if I create a class and implement IDisposable to get COM object so that I can use 'using' I get this error, Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem to 'System.IDisposable'. I am sorry to say that I don't have enough knowledge in this particular area and would appreciate your kind understanding.

Comment: A good article explaining how to release COM objects, https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2013/11/05/release-excel-com-objects/

Comment: You may find a lot of similar articles.